# Adding a hidden comment box to a listview of ParseObjects

Tags: android, listview, parse-platform

I'm creating a pretty straightforward app a user posts an update that is fed to the homepage, this is done with a custom list adapter and custom layout for the list. It all works fine but I want to make each item in the listView clickable that when clicked a hidden comment box drops down to allow the user to add a comment and when clicked again comment box hides but displays how many comments there are (similar to facebook). Can't find anything online specifically related to a comment box. I have read the androidhive tutorial on ExpandableListView which seems the right way to go about it just not sure how to customize it for a comment box. How would I go about achieving this?

ListAdapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ParseObject> {

private Context mContext;
private List<ParseObject> statusObj;

public ListAdapter(Context con, List<ParseObject> statusObj) {
    super(con, R.layout.customlistlayout, statusObj);
    mContext = con;
    this.statusObj = statusObj;
}

@Override //this inflates each row on homepage
public View getView(final int position, View convert, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;

    if (convert == null) { //if no view present create one
        convert = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.customlistlayout, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.statusHomePage = (TextView) convert.findViewById(R.id.statusHomePage);
        holder.userHomePage = (TextView) convert.findViewById(R.id.userHomePage);
        holder.timestampHomePage = (TextView) convert.findViewById(R.id.timestampHomePage);

        convert.setTag(holder);
    } else { 
        holder = (ViewHolder) convert.getTag();

    }

    //gets position of status in table from cloud database
    ParseObject status = statusObj.get(position);

    //sets username to the one who posted update
    String username = status.getString("Username");
    holder.userHomePage.setText(username);

    //sets status to the content user posted
    String userStatus = status.getString("Status");
    holder.statusHomePage.setText(userStatus);

    //sets the date and time for each post
    DateFormat df = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance();
    String timestamp = df.format(status.getCreatedAt());
    holder.timestampHomePage.setText(timestamp);

    return convert;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    TextView userHomePage;
    TextView statusHomePage;
    TextView timestampHomePage;
}
```

HomePage onCreate:

```
public class HomePage extends ListActivity {

private List<ParseObject> mStatus;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home_page);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setActionBar(toolbar);
        getActionBar().setTitle("Update Feed");

    ParseQuery<ParseObject> query = new ParseQuery<>("Status");
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
    query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
        @Override
        public void done(List<ParseObject> parseObjects, ParseException e) {
            if (e == null) {
                mStatus = parseObjects;

                ListAdapter list = new ListAdapter(getListView().getContext(), mStatus);
                setListAdapter(list);
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(HomePage.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

HomePage.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
tools:context="main.HomePage">

<Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"/>
```

CustomListLayout.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar1"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/userHomePage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_user"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="@string/UsernameCustom"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/statusHomePage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/status"
    android:textSize="18sp"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/timestampHomePage"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="end"
    android:text="@string/createdAt"
    android:textSize="14sp"/>
```

Comment: Why don't you add and EditText with set visiblity to View.INVISBLE and make it visbile on click of the button you can toggle the visibility Instead of making more comple ExpandableListview.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comment section, I would try just hiding/showing the comment section based on whether or not the item within the view has been touched.

You can target the commentLayout using `.findViewById(R.id.commentLayout)`, and then continue to use `.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)` and `.setVisibility(View.GONE);`

You may end up having to create a custom view class to respond to the touching of the view specifically, rather than the touching of the ListView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userHomePage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_user"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="@string/UsernameCustom"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusHomePage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/status"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timestampHomePage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="end"
        android:text="@string/createdAt"
        android:textSize="14sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/commentLayout"
        android:orientation="vertical">

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/tvComment"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:text="@string/createdAt"
              android:textSize="14sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>   
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is a sample of a ParseQueryAdapter that I used inside my application.

```
public class SportEventQueryAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<SportEvent> {

    // modify to show results based on relation. User should only see what
    // events he is associated with.

    public SportEventQueryAdapter(Context context, final ParseUser currentUser) {
        // Use the QueryFactory to construct a PQA that will only show
        // Todos marked as high-pri

        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<SportEvent>() {
            public ParseQuery<SportEvent> create() {
//              ParseQuery<SportEvent> query = new ParseQuery<SportEvent>(
//                      "SportEvent");
                ParseRelation relation = currentUser.getRelation("events");
                ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery();
                //query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                query.orderByDescending("events");
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(SportEvent event, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.gridview_detail, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(event, v, parent);

        // Add and download the image
        ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.ivMap);
        ParseFile imageFile = event.getParseFile("photo");
        if (imageFile != null) {
            todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
            todoImage.loadInBackground();
        }

        // Add the title view
        TextView typeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSportType);
        typeTextView.setText(event.getSport());
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        titleTextView.setText(event.getTitle());
        // Add the desc view
        TextView dateTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        dateTextView.setText(event.getDate());

        return v;

    }

}
```

Another Example

```
public class SportEventSearchQueryAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<SportEvent> {

    // modify constructor to take a zipcode, only show results near users
    // zipcode

    public SportEventSearchQueryAdapter(Context context,
            final ParseGeoPoint location, final String sportType, final int miles) {
        // Use the QueryFactory to construct a PQA that will only show
        // Todos marked as high-pri

        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<SportEvent>() {
            public ParseQuery<SportEvent> create() {
                ParseQuery<SportEvent> query = new ParseQuery<SportEvent>(
                        "SportEvent");
                query.whereEqualTo("sport", sportType);
                query.whereNear("location", location);
                query.whereWithinMiles("location", location, miles);
                query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                return query;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(SportEvent event, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.gridview_detail, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(event, v, parent);

        // Add and download the image
        ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.ivMap);
        ParseFile imageFile = event.getParseFile("photo");
        if (imageFile != null) {
            todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
            todoImage.loadInBackground();
        }

        // Add the title view
        TextView typeTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvSportType);
        typeTextView.setText(event.getSport());
        TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
        titleTextView.setText(event.getTitle());
        // Add the desc view
        TextView dateTextView = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.tvDate);
        dateTextView.setText(event.getDate());

        return v;

    }

}
```

Sample using Parse Relations

```
public class FriendQueryAdapter extends ParseQueryAdapter<ParseUser> {

    ImageButton btnAdd;
    ImageView ivAdd;

    public FriendQueryAdapter(Context context, final ParseUser currentUser) {

        // refine query to not show currentUser

        super(context, new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseUser>() {
            public ParseQuery<ParseUser> create() {
                // ParseQuery<ParseUser> query = ParseUser.getQuery();
                ParseRelation relation = currentUser.getRelation("Friends");
                ParseQuery query = relation.getQuery();
                query.orderByAscending("Friends");
                return query;

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public View getItemView(final ParseUser pUser, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (v == null) {
            v = View.inflate(getContext(), R.layout.search_detail, null);
        }

        super.getItemView(pUser, v, parent);

        ParseImageView todoImage = (ParseImageView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.imageViewSearch);
        ParseFile imageFile = pUser.getParseFile("photo");
        if (imageFile != null) {
            todoImage.setParseFile(imageFile);
            todoImage.loadInBackground();
        }

        // Add the title view
        final TextView titleTextView = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewSearch);
        titleTextView.setText(pUser.getUsername());

        final TextView titleTextViewTagline = (TextView) v
                .findViewById(R.id.textViewSearchTagline);
        titleTextViewTagline.setText(pUser.getString("tagline"));

        return v;

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks will give this a try, can I stack multiple comments this way? Just trying to figure out how to incorporate Parse to store and retrieve the comments and link them to each item

Comment: You can definitely add more LinearLayouts with different IDs and hide/show them. You can create an Object that extends ParseObject, and then add methods to set/get the items of that object. When you say comments, can users add multiple comments to say a post of some type? or is it a singular object and has at most 3 comments which could be predefined?

Comment: Well it's an update feed so ideally I want multiple comments to be created and added dynamically rather than having a set limit predefined

Comment: You may want to look into ParseQueryAdapter (I think that is what it is called), it could help you when trying to query a objects from the Parse DB. I would also look into making a Comment Object, and perhaps a Post Object (Whatever type of feed item you want to call it). You can run a query on a specific Parse Object ID, and get all Comment relations and just store them in the Comment Parse Object and populate your list view.

Comment: I just updated my answer to show some samples of ParseQueryAdapter.